# RAW partitions to NTFS

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning

i'v just installed windows 8.1 to a new laptop, i created 3 partitions on the hard drive during the installation process, after i installed the windows i can't find the other two partitions, it's only the C partition when i open my computer window, i checked using disk management, the two partitions were there, they are primary but the file system is set to RAW, I've been googling for an hour but i'm not sure how do i get my partitions working, it's a new laptop so there is no need for any data recovering.

Comment: If there are RAW then they don't have a filesystem.

Comment: @Ramhound any idea how to fix this!

Comment: format the partitions so they have a filesystem

Comment: @Ramhound i did format them, and they both NTFS now, but still can't find them when i open my coumputer window!!

Comment: @Adam: In Disk Management (Start > Run > diskmgmt.msc) right-click and assign drive letters to those partitions.

Comment: @Adam: You're welcome, congrats on getting it to work. :) BTW you can self-accept your answer after 2 days I think (if I remember correctly).

Comment: @Karan i wasn't sure how to end the question, so i thought if i posted an answer for it, it would be closed, but clearly it's not.

Comment: @Adam: Others can't close your question for you, only the question asker can. For new users with low rep there is a 48 hour cooling period I believe, which is to give others a chance to post a better solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

using Start > Run > diskmgmt.msc
two steps:
1. format the partitions
2. right-click and assign drive letters to those partitions